# Attach Image to email from byte

Tags: c#, angularjs, wcf, rest, arrays

I am busy trying to understand how to work with images from a `website -> service -> email`.

What I have done so far is converting the image to `base64` then uploading it to my service. Next I convert it to a byte array and then store it into my database.

At the same time when inserting the byte into my database I want to send the image by attaching it to an email.

At this time the attachment is only a file that I cannot open, so I guess it is just a byte array and not an Image.

**C#**

```
public string SendEmail(string send)
        {
            try
            {
                TestDb db = new TestDb();

                TestImage result = new TestImage();
                string[] arData = send.Split('|');

                byte[] bytes = new byte[arData[0].Length * sizeof(char)];
                System.Buffer.BlockCopy(arData[0].ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                result.TestImg = bytes;
                result.TestId = int.Parse(arData[1].ToString());

                db.TestImage.Attach(result);
                db.TestImage.Add(result);
                db.SaveChanges();

                string foto = "name";

                Attachment att = new Attachment(new MemoryStream(bytes), foto);

                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential("Test@gmail.com", "Test123");

                mail.To.Add("Test@gmail.com");
                mail.Subject = "subject Test";
                mail.Attachments.Add(att);
                mail.From = new MailAddress("Test@gmail.com");
                System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Credentials = cred;
                smtp.Send(mail);
                return result.Id.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

**Angularjs**

```
$scope.link = '\img\ionic.png';
var imageData=$base64.encode($scope.link);

  $scope.sendimg = function() {

    console.log(imageData);
    $http.post("http://localhost:53101/TruckService.svc/sendEmail/" + imageData + '|' + 1
    )
              .success(function(data) { 
 })

          .error(function(data) {
              console.log("failure");
              })    
  }
```

Comment: Try this way, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript

Comment: I already convert the image to base64 in my js? @DilumN

Comment: Then did you check whether imageData has correct encoded image by converting back imageData to image from a tool??

Comment: no I have not what tool do you use? @DilumN

Comment: Test your imageData with this, http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter

Comment: ok yeah it is corrupt, I will try your first suggestion then.

Comment: you can provide an answer for your comment and I will accept it thanks. @DilumN

Comment: Add these steps as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with converting image to base64. So check whether you have correct image in `imageData` by convert it back to an image.

You can use online tools to converto base64 to image [Link](http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter)

So if it's the problem, try to convert your image as below,

```
function toDataUrl(url, callback, outputFormat){
    var img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
    img.onload = function(){
        var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var dataURL;
        canvas.height = this.height;
        canvas.width = this.width;
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat);
        callback(dataURL);
        canvas = null; 
    };
    img.src = url;
}

toDataUrl('url', function(base64Img){
    // Base64DataURL
});
```

Comment: Thanks could answer!

Answer (score 0):

In my case it comes from my Resources. But in the end its the same. After maken a byte[] I attach it like this:

```
byte[] logo = BmpToBytes_MemStream(Properties.Resources.gcs_logo);
emailMessage.Attachments.AddFileAttachment("logo.jpg", logo);
emailMessage.Attachments[emailMessage.Attachments.Count - 1].IsInline = true;
emailMessage.Attachments[emailMessage.Attachments.Count - 1].ContentId = "gcs_logo.jpg";

private static byte[] BmpToBytes_MemStream(Bitmap bmp)
{
    byte[] bmpBytes = null;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        // Save to memory using the Jpeg format
        bmp.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        // read to end
        bmpBytes = ms.GetBuffer();
        bmp.Dispose();
    }

    return bmpBytes;
}
```

Hope this helps.